# Can I store a fieldlist in a variable for use in other queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a temptable holding fields that need to be exported for different client-reports. The table works as an interface: the client deletes and adds fields and we generate reports accordingly. To easily export, we use the following snippets:

```
-- Compile select list
select top 1
    stuff((
        select ',' + 'cast([' + Column + '] as nvarchar(max)) as ' + Column
        from #report_fields a
        where a.FieldType like 'X' or a.FieldType like 'Y'
        for XML path('')
     ),1,1,'') as document_fields
from #report_fields a
;
```

This results in a list like

```
cast([Field1] as nvarchar(max)) as Field1,
cast([Field2] as nvarchar(max)) as Field2,
cast([Field3] as nvarchar(max)) as Field3,
...
cast([FieldN] as nvarchar(max)) as FieldN
```

To use in a query like

```
select
    cast([Field1] as nvarchar(max)) as Field1,
    cast([Field2] as nvarchar(max)) as Field2,
    cast([Field3] as nvarchar(max)) as Field3,
    ...
    cast([FieldN] as nvarchar(max)) as FieldN
into
    #client_fields_temp
from
    dbo.ClientData
```

I do this throughout the script. Howver, it requires manual running of the 1st query and copy-pasting the result (the field list) into the second query. I would like to automate this. Is it possible to store the fieldist in a variable and use something like this:

```
-- Compile select list
@fieldlist = select top 1
    stuff((
        select ',' + 'cast([' + Column + '] as nvarchar(max)) as ' + Column
        from #report_fields a
        where a.FieldType like 'X' or a.FieldType like 'Y'
        for XML path('')
     ),1,1,'') as document_fields
from #report_fields a
;

select
    @fieldlist
into
    #client_fields_temp
from
    dbo.ClientData
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, via dynamic SQL. Please read up on that.

Comment: Ah, I know but this has many disadvantages (temp tables created within a dynamic query are not available outside the dyn. query, global temp tables I would rather avoid, the IDE color coding is all off because everything is considered a string, etc.). I was therefore hoping for basically any other solution :-)

Comment: Seeing that you are getting the fields like this in the first place, I hardly think there's another option. But I might be totally wrong of course :D

Comment: Why do you need the temporary table?  If you have the query, you can run that in most contexts where you would use a temporary table.